# Getting 500 error on simple form POST via AJAX -- not sure what's wrong?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I don't understand why I'm getting a 500 error on this simple AJAX-based form POST to PHP.... Mind taking a look? It's probably something simple I'm just not catching but I'm scratching my head right now.

JS:

```
    $form.submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = $form.serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: $form.attr('action'),
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData
        }).done(function(res) {
            console.dir(res);
            alert('success!'); // update status text
            $form[0].reset(); // reset the form
            $form.find('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }).fail(function(data) {
            alert('error');
        });
    });
```

PHP:

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

  if( !empty($_POST['captcha']) ) {
    processForm( $_POST['formName'] );
  } else {
    http_response_code(401);
    echo "Unauthorized.";
  }
} else {
    // not valid. ignore
    http_response_code(400);
    echo "Bad Request.";
}
```

PHP: processForm():

```
function processForm(string $type) {

    if ($type == 'contact') {
        http_response_code(200);
        echo "contact form";
    }
    if ($type == 'appointmentRequest') {
        http_response_code(200);
        echo "appointment form";
    }

    // send the email

    // return confirmation / failure

    // die

}
```

I'm just getting a 500 error. I am sure the request is pointing to the right location.

Comment: You may have some error in `processForm`. What does that code look like?

Comment: @jrubins not much right now, I've just stubbed in some success codes and simple string echo. I added it to my original post.

Comment: Look in your server error log. Find the actual *cause* of the 500 error.

Comment: If you're getting a 500 error, it means the script is failing. Check your PHP error log.

Comment: Hmm, I've frequently gotten 500 errors with Ajax requests to a PHP backend when I have a stupid syntax error in the PHP. You could try commenting out the line for `processForm`, running the request again and seeing if you still get the 500.

Comment: Looks like $_POST['formName'] contains no type or is not set.

Comment: So it seems that the issue is the type hinting in the `processForm()` method... If I remove the `string` it works. Any idea why this is? I've also tried casting the `$type` param as a string and it still failed so not sure why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry but as you can read in [PHP 5 documentation](http://php.net/manual/kr/language.oop5.typehinting.php):

> Type Hints can only be of the `object` and `array` (since PHP 5.1) type. Traditional type hinting with `int` and `string` isn't supported.

Since string is not a class, you can't "type-hint" it in your function therefore getting the error.

You can check if it's a string using other methods like [filter_input](http://php.net/manual/es/function.filter-input.php)

Comment: Thanks, this was it -- Teaches me for not reading the documentation and assuming it supported primitive type hinting ;) Thanks!